# Built-in Evil mode for Emacs 24

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I've read in a lot of places such as the WikEmacs (http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Evil) that Emacs24 already came with support for Evil mode, no need to install it via el-get. But I can't seem to understand how do I activate it.

I tried just adding the

(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

lines to my .emacs but it can't seem to work, how do you guys use the built-in evil mode on emacs24? without cloning git repositories, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The statement on WikEmacs is false; evil-mode is *not* included in Emacs 24. (As it's a wiki, I just edited the page and removed that text.)

There are many ways to install evil-mode. I'd suggest activating the [MELPA](http://melpa.org/) package repository by adding the following to your `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

Then type `M-x list-packages`, find `evil` in the list, and install it.

Comment: That made sense! I found strange that I couldn't see any mention of this in other sites, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: OTOH there is `viper-mode` which is another VI "emulator" which comes bundled with Emacs (since for ever or so).